# Why is my program making endless GET requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, soundcloud

The program is meant to post the location of a recent SoundCloud upload on a Google Map when the update button is pressed. populate() is called each time the "update" button is pressed and will either post one of the locations on the map or call findLocations() which repopulates the array. For some reason findLocations() is making infinite requests when it is called by populate(). This is my first program in JavaScript so it's probably a pretty noob mistake, if someone could shed light on this it would be great! GitHub link is here as well.

edit: findLocations() works when I set breakpoints and step through the program. I'm starting to think the problem might have to do with the fact that the GET request is an asynchronous call. Here what I think is happening:

1. "update" button is pressed and locate() is called
2. addresses appears empty so locate calls findLocations()
3. findLocations() asynchronously requests GET "/tracks" resulting in the creation of thread A and B.
4. Thread A enters the callback function of request and updates the 'addresses' array. Thread B leaves findLocations() (without executing the callback function), returns to locate() to recursively call itself. Because this happened faster then thread A was able to update 'addresses', 'addresses' still appears empty and calls therefore findLocations again, repeating the process from step 3.

Does this theory sound legit and if so how would I go about testing this?

https://github.com/blasian/soundcloud-map/tree/drunk

```
var locations = [];
var offset = 10;    

// Create locations array
function findLocations() {
    SC.get("/tracks", { limit: 10, offset: offset }, function(tracks){
        offset += 10;
        for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
            SC.get("/users/" + tracks[i].user_id, function(user){
                if (user.country) { 
                    locations.push(user.country);
                    console.log(user.country);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

// Add next location to map
function locate() {
    console.log(locations);
    if (locations.length > 0) {
        gcode(locations.pop());
    } else {
        findLocations();
        locate();
    }
}
```

Comment: And are you sure tracks is only returning 10 items?

Comment: No it seems to be making an infinite amount of requests. Except for when I step through it, then it works :/

Comment: This would happen if locations is not getting filled in with data - each time, it's length is zero. Try logging locations.

Comment: @blzn add some logs to the functions,  ie.  Log `tracks.length` and `offset`

Comment: @JAL I'm logging locations in locate() but I can't read it because my console gets filled with GET requests and then crashes each time findLocations() is ran. I also can't debug setting breakpoints because whenever I do that it works correctly. Do you have any suggestions on how I should debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a recursive function:

```
function locate() {
    if (locations.length > 0) {
        // recursion stops here
    } else {
        // updateLocationsUsingAJAX()
        // recursion continues here
        locate();
    }
}
```

This is does not work the way you expect:

1. By the time the AJAX request updates the `locations` variable, JavaScript has already fired hundreds of AJAX requests
2. In fact, the AJAX callback will not be fired because JavaScript is too busy calling the recursive function recursively (the callback that update variable get queued waiting for JavaScript to become idle)

The solution is to re-arrange the code so that you process the locations variable -OR- fire next AJAX request inside the AJAX callback function.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks so much, that's the perfect solution!